# Postgres: SELECT where a list of JOINed subtables contains specific data

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In our project we have a table `events` each of which can have multiple `dates`. This means each row in `dates` has a `event_id` and a `position` where `position` (starting at 0) is unique within the same `event_id`. `dates` also (obviously) has a `date` column.

Now I want to select all `events` which have a specific list of `date` child values (ordered by `position`). Is this possible within a single SQL query?

**Example Tables**

```
events:  (id, name, event_type, description, comment, user_id)
dates:   (id, event_id, position, date_at, latitude, longitude, location)
```

`id`, position and lat/long columns are integer, `date_at` is a DATE, the rest are strings (character varying) which don't really matter here. For example:

```
INSERT INTO events (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Birthday Party');
INSERT INTO dates (id, event_id, position, date_at) VALUES ( 1, 1, 0, '2014-06-30');
INSERT INTO dates (id, event_id, position, date_at) VALUES ( 2, 1, 1, '2015-06-30');
INSERT INTO dates (id, event_id, position, date_at) VALUES ( 3, 1, 2, '2016-06-30');
INSERT INTO dates (id, event_id, position, date_at) VALUES ( 4, 1, 3, '2017-06-30');
INSERT INTO dates (id, event_id, position, date_at) VALUES ( 5, 1, 4, '2018-06-30');
INSERT INTO events (id, name) VALUES (2, 'S.O. Birthday Party');
INSERT INTO dates (id, event_id, position, date_at) VALUES ( 6, 2, 0, '2014-02-11');
INSERT INTO dates (id, event_id, position, date_at) VALUES ( 7, 2, 1, '2015-02-11');
INSERT INTO dates (id, event_id, position, date_at) VALUES ( 8, 2, 2, '2016-02-11');
INSERT INTO dates (id, event_id, position, date_at) VALUES ( 9, 2, 3, '2017-02-11');
INSERT INTO dates (id, event_id, position, date_at) VALUES (10, 2, 4, '2018-02-11');
```

I need a query that returns `Event #1` when I feed it this array of dates: `[2014-06-30, 2015-06-30, 2016-06-30, 2017-06-30, 2018-06-30]`. The whole query string array will be automatically generated, so it can have any format and can be hardcoded in this example (we use Ruby on Rails). The list of possible events will have other restrictions (user_id, event_type, etc) so it won't be a long list (perhaps 10..100 events), so it need not be an indexable query.

It should not return Event #1 when fed these dates in another order or other dates or a subset of these dates. It should accept any number of dates as input, including an empty set.

Comment: Can you post the tables? Want to make sure in visualizing this correctly

Comment: Are the order of your dates the same as the index in `position`?  If so, you can probably eliminate that column completely.

Comment: Clockworks, is that so? In the Postgres 9.3 docs under "ORDER BY clause", it says "If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume for the moment that you have created an additional table in which to store you `list of specific dates`

```
SELECT
  event.*
FROM
  events
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    d.event_id
  FROM
    dates           AS d
  INNER JOIN
    list_of_dates   AS l
      ON l.date = d.date
  GROUP BY
    d.event_id
  HAVING
        COUNT(*)        = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list_of_dates)
    AND MAX(d.position) = MIN(d.position) + COUNT(*) - 1
)
  AS list
    ON list.event_id = events.id
```

This joins the `dates` table to the list of dates that you have.

It then groups the results by `event_id`.

The `HAVING` clause then only allows through an `event_id` if the returned number of dates matches the number in the list.  (If I join 5 dates, I want only the `event_id`s that include all 5 of those dates).

The `HAVING` clause then ensure that all of those dates are sequential.  If I have a list of 5 dates, the `MAX(position)` should be 4 more than the `MIN(position)`

I'm not actually sure if that last criteria is what you wanted, but hopefully it will give you a structure to work with for the criteria that you do need.

Also, note that this will require a full table scan.  This type of multi-row search is always slow in SQL.  *(Academically, it's the same as searching an Entity-Attribute-Value table.)*

**EDIT:** In response to question edit.

If hard-coding the dates into the query, you could do the following, but you ***must*** be crucially aware of the possibility of SQL Injection Attacks if *any* part of the query is controlled by the user.

```
SELECT
  event.*
FROM
  events
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    event_id
  FROM
    dates           AS d
  WHERE
    date IN ('2014-06-30', '2015-06-30', '2016-06-30', '2017-06-30', '2018-06-30')
  GROUP BY
    event_id
  HAVING
        COUNT(*)        = 5
    AND MAX(d.position) = MIN(d.position) + 5 - 1
)
  AS list
    ON list.event_id = events.id
```

You would hard code both the list of dates and the two occurrences of the `5`.

With regards to you requirement of `so it need not be an indexable query`, you will find that this is in fact impossible, to a degree.  I'll try to explain why...

There is no mechanism to interrogate multiple rows *together and at the same time*.  You *do* get *simultaneously*, but also *individually*.  What I mean by that is that you can check `is the date on this row in my list of dates`?  What you can't do is to say `are all of these dates in my list`.

The query above checks each row one at a time, *is this date in my list*, ***then*** calculates *how many matched* and *were they all in order* in the HAVING clause.   If any event has any one of those dates you still need to process that date, then process the HAVING clause and only then realise that not all of the dates were present.

Each individual *is this date in my list* can be `indexable`, but the final HAVING clause will be a full scan of those matches.  The result is that this *does not* scale particularly well at all.  And there is very little that can be done about that.

Depending on the statistical structure of your data, you may be able to make minor, and quite esoteric, optimisations.  For example...

```
INSERT INTO
  dates (id, event_id, first_position, date0, date1, date2, date3, date4, date5)
VALUES
  ( 1, 1, 0, '2014-06-30', '2015-06-30', '2016-06-30', '2017-06-30', '2018-06-30', NULL ),
  ( 1, 1, 1, '2015-06-30', '2016-06-30', '2017-06-30', '2018-06-30', NULL, NULL ),
  ( 1, 1, 2, '2016-06-30', '2017-06-30', '2018-06-30', NULL, NULL, NULL ),
  ( 1, 1, 3, '2017-06-30', '2018-06-30', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL ),
  ( 1, 1, 4, '2018-06-30', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL )
;

SELECT
  events.*
FROM
  events
INNER JOIN
  dates
    ON dates.event_id = events.id
WHERE
      dates.date0 = '2015-06-30'
  AND dates.date1 = '2016-06-30'
  AND dates.date2 = '2017-06-30'
;
```

Now, you could have an index on `(date0, event_id)` and quickly find all the events that have `'2015-06-30'` as one of the dates.  You would also only get back one row from the `dates` table, and can quickly check if all of the other dates are also present.

It's dirty though. If an event could have 100 associated dates, you'd need 100 date fields.  That also makes in inflexible (you might provision 128 dates, then in the future find you need 129).  It also makes writing queries against it a bit messy (you're not passing parameters, you're writing a WHERE clause).

The *index seek* on `date0` is still going to return rows that are later discarded by the remained of the where clause, but it's very likely that you'll get fewer of these cases than by using the HAVING clause method; so it should be faster.  Unless you have so many columns that the extra i/o of reading so many redundant columns counters your savings.  Over-all I'd still expect this to be measurably faster, and yet I'd still be very apprehensive of trying it.

Unfortunately the concept of searching multiple rows within grouped rows is always going to be messy and/or costly to execute.

Comment: How would I modify this query if the list of dates is hardcoded in the query (as in my example I added above)? I can probably skip the inner INNER JOIN (:-) ). Right?

Comment: @Jens - The `INNER JOIN` is only needed to translate the `event_id` into a `name`.  If all you need is the `id`, skip the outer query all together.  The rest of your simple question is rather involved so I've updated my answer.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much - I'm always amazed at what high quality answers you get at StackOverflow. Dont't be afraid of SQL injection attacks, the list of dates will not be user controlled and all other user controllable parameters are integers (and will be forcibly casted to integer).